# Replace data in a column varchar (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am using Oracle PL/SQL. I have a varchar column `Filtre` and I want to change the data

Example :

```
Filtre = "User@12.4|Tab@3.15.16.25.12.1.4|Sort@3.4.15.12"
```

I need to change the values between `Tab@3.15.16.25.12.1.4|`.
As an example I replace 15 by 18 and 16 by 19.

Thanks

Comment: You need to give more input, can you read it or not? Can you use a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm) to define the change? Or substring? Do you want to do this based on what criteria?

Comment: Also if this is for PL/SQL you might want to include the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem

create table temp as

select

cle, 
debut||

regexp_replace(
replace(replace(replace(fin, '.20.', '.34.'), '.24','.35'), '.26','.36')
,'.(.*).','\1')

resultat 
from
(
select
cle,

regexp_replace(ligne,'(.*COLTAB@).*','\1') debut,

regexp_replace(ligne,'(.*COLTAB@)(.*)\|','.\2.') fin

from
(
select ID cle, filtre ligne From favoris where Type ='Test'
)
);

UPDATE favoris f SET f.filtre = (SELECT t.resultat
                                  FROM temp t 
                                  WHERE f.ID = t.cle)
     where Type='Test';

drop table temp;

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some generic functions provided by Oracle, that should be enough to help you further. Take a look at the Oracle functions REPLACE, INSTR, SUBSTR, TRANSLATE.
With INSTR you can find the location of a string within another string. So INSTR( filtre, 15, m, n) returns the n-th appearance starting from position m location of 15 in your string. Not knowing what the requirements are, I'm not sure if you can do with a simple REPLACE, or that you need to dive a little deeper and use functions like SUBSTR. Remember, you can nest those functions and probably need to do that many times to get the desired result. I'd stay away from regular expressions from now, first try to master the basic functions in PL/SQL/

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/index.php